# How can I set specific zooms/resolutions in Openlayers 3 zoom control?

Tags: openlayers

I want to have only specific zooms in my zoom cotrol so the map opens in zoom 3 , when click the zoom in it goes to 6 -> 12 -> 16 and back when zoom out.

How is this doable in OL 3 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pretty easy , just didn't find it in documentation api.

```
var resolutions = [305.74811309814453,76.43702827453613,9.109257068634033,9.554628534317017];

var view = new ol.View({
    projection: 'EPSG:3857',   
    resolutions: resolutions,
    center: center,
    zoom: 9,
    minZoom: 9,
    maxZoom: 16
});
```